# Can't assigned value to object

Tags: ruby

```
class Hero
attr_reader :hp
def initialize(name, level, job, hp, strength)
    @name = name
    @level = level.to_i
    @job = job
    @hp = hp.to_i
    @strength = strength.to_i
end

def get_name
    @name
end

def profile
    puts "#{@name} level is #{@level} and hp: #{@hp}"
end

def attack(target) 
    #this line
    target.hp -= @strength
end

def get_hp
    @hp
end
end

#name, level, class/job, hp, strength
yamato = Hero.new("Kross", 16, "Knight", 10, 10)
ciguapal = Hero.new("Ciguapal", 20, "Ghost", 15, 10)


puts yamato.attack(ciguapal)
```

When I run the script, this is what I get:

'calc.rb:20:in `attack`': undefined method `hp=' for #<Hero:0x2eac850> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  hp
        from calc.rb:33:in`'

I'm trying to lower the hp of the second object, through the first object. Doing an "attack". But I don't understand why I keep getting this error.

However, if I just print target.hp it does work.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use consistent indentation. Most Rubyists opt for two-spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr_reader :hp` just generates a getter method for `@hp`. But in the `attack` method you call to set `hp`, because

```
target.hp -= @strength
```

is the same as

```
target.hp = target.hp - @strength
```

Just change

```
attr_reader :hp
```

to

```
attr_accessor :hp
```

to fix this issue.